# Fetch API call not working when executed in React-Native

Tags: react-native, fetch

I am trying to make a fetch API call in React Native:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    TouchableHighlight,
    View
} from 'react-native';

class AwesomeProject extends Component {
    render() {
        return (    
            <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <TextInput 
                placeholder="Enter Text to Be Validated"
                style={{height: 65, width: 275, fontSize: 22}} 
                onSubmitEditing={(event) => {
                    var apiKey = "someAPIKey"
                    var encodedAddress = encodeURIComponent(event.nativeEvent.text)
                    fetch("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + encodedAddress + "&key=" + apiKey)
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .then(json => {
                            if (json.status === "OK") {
                                console.log(json.results.formatted_address)
                            }
                            else {
                                console.log("Invalid")
                            }
                    })
                        .catch(err => console.err(err))
                }}
               />   
          </View>
    );
}
```

However, the callback registered to onSubmitEditing only works when tested outside of React-Native. Does anyone know of an explanation??

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`if (json.status === "OK") {
   console.log(json.results[0].formatted_address)
}`

I did some digging and I saw that the returned JSON had a status property, and a results array. You can access the first item in that results array with `results[0]`.